# How best to rechunk a NetCDF file collection to Zarr dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf4, dask-distributed, zarr

I'm trying to rechunk a NetCDF file collection and create a Zarr dataset on AWS S3. I have 168 original NetCDF4 classic files with arrays of dimension `time: 1, y: 3840, x: 4608` chunked as `chunks={'time':1, 'y':768, 'x':922}`.

I want to write this output to Zarr, and I want to optimize for time series extraction, so include more time records in my chunks.  I figured I would use xarray to help get the job done, since I have a lot of processors available to take advantage of Dask, and xarray has both `xr.open_mfdataset` and `ds.to_zarr`.

I first tried rechunking to `chunks={'time':24, 'y':768, 'x':922}` to match the input NetCDF4 chunking in `x` and `y`, but when I tried to write to Zarr it complained because it needed uniform chunk sizes in both `x` and `y`, only allowing non-uniform size in the last chunk along the `time` dimension (and unfortunately in the `x` dimension, the total size 4608 is not a multiple of chunk size 922.

So then I tried `chunks={'time':168, 'y':384, 'x':288}` and that started working, and proceeded very quickly for a few minutes, then got slower and slower.  Eventually after 50 minutes, the cluster died with:

```
4072 distributed.core - INFO - Event loop was unresponsive in Worker for 1.41s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
4073 slurmstepd: error: Step 3294889.0 exceeded memory limit (25346188 > 25165824), being killed
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from dask.distributed import Client

import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import s3fs
import zarr

client = Client(scheduler_file='/home/rsignell/scheduler.json')
client
```

[image]

```
root = '/lustre/projects/hazards/cmgp/woodshole/rsignell/nwm/forcing_short_range/' 

bucket_endpoint='https://s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/'

f_zarr = 'rsignell/nwm/test_week4'

dates = pd.date_range(start='2018-04-01T00:00', end='2018-04-07T23:00', freq='H')

urls = ['{}{}/nwm.t{}z.short_range.forcing.f001.conus.nc'.format(root,a.strftime('%Y%m%d'),a.strftime('%H')) for a in dates]

ds = xr.open_mfdataset(urls, concat_dim='time', chunks={'time':1, 'y':768, 'x':922})
ds = ds.drop(['ProjectionCoordinateSystem','time_bounds'])
ds = ds.chunk(chunks={'time':168, 'y':384, 'x':288}).persist()
ds
```

producing

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (reference_time: 168, time: 168, x: 4608, y: 3840)
Coordinates:
  * reference_time  (reference_time) datetime64[ns] 2018-04-01 ...
  * x               (x) float64 -2.304e+06 -2.303e+06 -2.302e+06 -2.301e+06 ...
  * y               (y) float64 -1.92e+06 -1.919e+06 -1.918e+06 -1.917e+06 ...
  * time            (time) datetime64[ns] 2018-04-01T01:00:00 ...
Data variables:
    T2D             (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<shape=(168, 3840, 4608), chunksize=(168, 384, 288)>
    LWDOWN          (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<shape=(168, 3840, 4608), chunksize=(168, 384, 288)>
    Q2D             (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<shape=(168, 3840, 4608), chunksize=(168, 384, 288)>
    U2D             (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<shape=(168, 3840, 4608), chunksize=(168, 384, 288)>
    V2D             (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<shape=(168, 3840, 4608), chunksize=(168, 384, 288)>
    PSFC            (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<shape=(168, 3840, 4608), chunksize=(168, 384, 288)>
    RAINRATE        (time, y, x) float32 dask.array<shape=(168, 3840, 4608), chunksize=(168, 384, 288)>
    SWDOWN          (time, y, x) float64 dask.array<shape=(168, 3840, 4608), chunksize=(168, 384, 288)>
```

Then I call

```
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False, client_kwargs=dict(endpoint_url=bucket_endpoint))
d = s3fs.S3Map(f_zarr, s3=fs)

compressor = zarr.Blosc(cname='zstd', clevel=3, shuffle=2)
encoding = {vname: {'compressor': compressor} for vname in ds.data_vars}

delayed_store = ds.to_zarr(store=d, mode='w', encoding=encoding, compute=False)
persist_store = delayed_store.persist(retries=100)
```

and just before it dies, the Dask Daskboard looks like this:

[image]
[image]

The total size of the NetCDF4 files is 20GB, so it seems a bit crazy that I've got over 500GB showing in the Dask Dashboard, and that 30 processors each with 60GB RAM is not sufficient for the job.

What am I doing wrong, or what would be a better solution?

Comment: What is your memory usage after the completion of the first dataset `.persist()` ?

Comment: Can you try persisting the full dataset prior to the `to_zarr` step?

Comment: I do use `.persist()` on the dataset load above, and actually, this is where it crashes with `slurmstepd: error: Step 3295169.0 exceeded memory limit (126726200 > 125829120), being killed
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 3295169.0 ON n3-86 CANCELLED AT 2018-04-23T10:33:50 ***
slurmstepd: error: Exceeded job memory limit`

Answer (score 3):

I notice that you say you want to *increase* the number of chunks in the time dimension. Or maybe I've misunderstood.

You start with chunks specified as `chunks={'time':1, 'y':768, 'x':922}`, but then try `chunks={'time':168, 'y':384, 'x':288}` and find that the second one uses a large amount of memory.

The problem is that the `chunks` keyword specifies the *size* of the chunks, not the *number* of chunks!

In the first case the size of each chunk is `1*768*922 ~ 7e5`, whereas in the second case the size of each chunk is `168*384*288 ~ 2e7`.

The maximum number of chunks in time is achieved by `chunks={'time': 1}`.